# Grep thinks text file is binary, but it isn't

Tags: windows, text, grep, binaryfiles, git-bash

I came across a `.cpp` file in our codebase that is seen as binary by grep. So I can't grep it like a text file, which is annoying and obviously not how things ought to be. So I want to know why grep thinks the file is binary and address the issue.

I tried to find any characters out of the ordinary using the command

```
grep -Pna --color -r "[\x00-\x08]|[\x10-\x19]|[\x80-\xFF]" test.cpp
```

but it doesn't yield any matches.

How can figure out the cause of this problem?

I should mention I'm on windows git bash.

Output of locale:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Maybe try running it through `iconv` to see if it has any Unicode characters in it.

Comment: That sounds like the file contains a byte sequence that isn't legal for your current locale. Could you edit your question ton include the output of the `locale` command?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19907/what-makes-grep-consider-a-file-to-be-binary/204620#204620

Comment: @MarkSetchell iconv gives the position of the problem. Thanks. Investigating this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you’re using MS Windows, it’s possible that the `test.cpp` file is encoded using either UTF-16 (common in recent versions of Windows) or Windows-1252 (CP-1252) as its character encoding (perhaps a typographic quote in one of the comments).

When your locale is set to UTF-8 and `grep` detects invalid characters for that locale, it assumes that the file is binary. A quick way around this issue, is to get `grep` to use the `C` locale by temporarily modifying the `LC_ALL` environment variable when running the `grep` command:

```
LC_ALL=C grep pattern test.cpp
```

A better long term solution would be to convert text files (using `iconv` or your favourite text editor) to use UTF-8 as their character encoding.

Comment: You were right, there was a typographic quotes inside a string somewhere, probably inserted by tools that use ANSI/windows-1252 encodings. Thanks!

Comment: My grep command probably didn't find it as a quote is a continuation character in utf-8 (which is my locale setting). I should have tested on byte level instead, bypassing the utf-8 encoding.